# Prestashop 1.7 hide content on mobile

Tags: php, mobile, conditional-statements, smarty, prestashop-1.7

In prestashop 1.7 how can I show/hide custom content (images, html blocks etc), specifically for mobile devices? Does this use smarty (or php) in tpl files?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried. Since your question is too broad

Comment: Use CSS `@media` rules

Comment: @Cashbee 
Sorry no,
I need to REMOVE from DOM

Comment: @Himanshu have no code because I don't know the way to do that

Comment: If you need to remove the elements you can use jQuery $(window).width() and if it's less than you need just remove your elements $('element').remove()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MobileDetect` library:

```
public function hookDisplayHeader() 
{
    if (Context::getContext()->getMobileDevice()) {
        //content for mobile devices
    } else {
        //content for not mobile devices
    }
}
```